# Query maximum N records of each group base on a condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have a question regarding querying data in MongoDB. Here is my sample data:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "category": "fruit",
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Banana"
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "category": "fruit",
    "userId": 2,
    "name": "Apple"
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "category": "fresh-food",
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Fish"
},
{
    "_id": 4,
    "category": "fresh-food",
    "userId": 2,
    "name": "Shrimp"
},
{
    "_id": 5,
    "category": "vegetable",
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Salad"
},
{
    "_id": 6,
    "category": "vegetable",
    "userId": 2,
    "name": "carrot"
}
```

The requirements:

1. If the `category` is `fruit`, returns all the records match
2. If the `category` is NOT fruit, returns maximum 10 records of each category grouped by user
3. The category is known and stable, so we can hard-coded in our query.

I want to get it done in a single query. So the result expected should be:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        ... // All records of 
    ],
    "fresh-food": [
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "data": [
            // Top 10 records of user 1 with category = "fresh-food"
            ]
        },
        {
            "userId": 2,
            "data": [
            // Top 10 records of user 2 with category = "fresh-food"
            ]
        },
        ...
    ],
    "vegetable": [
    {
            "userId": 1,
            "data": [
            // Top 10 records of user 1 with category = "vegetable"
            ]
        },
        {
            "userId": 2,
            "data": [
            // Top 10 records of user 2 with category = "vegetable"
            ]
        },
    ]   
}
```

I've found the guideline to group by each group using `$group` and `$slice`, but I can't apply the requirement number #1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregation for this

- `$facet` to categorize incoming data, we categorized into two. 1. Fruit and 2. non_fruit
- `$match` to match the condition
- `$group` first group to group the data based on category and user. Second group to group by its category only
- `$objectToArray` to make the object into key value pair
- `$replaceRoot` to make the non_fruit to root with fruit

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "fruit": [
        { $match: { "category": "fruit"  } }
      ],
      "non_fruit": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [ "$category", "fruit" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { c: "$category", u: "$userId" },
            data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.c",
            v: {
              $push: {
                uerId: "$_id.u",
                data: { "$slice": [ "$data", 3 ] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $addFields: {  "k": "$_id", _id: "$$REMOVE" } }        
      ]
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { non_fruit: { "$arrayToObject": "$non_fruit" } }},
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [ "$$ROOT", "$non_fruit" ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { non_fruit: 0 } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lhl5nqbRHta)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems that it works, but as I pointed out the requirement for non_fruit data is that If the category is NOT fruit, returns maximum 10 records of each category grouped by user. The query you showed still return all records of each category, how do we limit them?

Comment: @TunzDaoz you need random 10 data o user??

Comment: Yes, any records, as long as it is limited to 10. Like a shipper can only deliver 10 products at a time, any of them is fine.

Comment: @TunzDaoz I have updated.. added `$slice`